# cdf in tikz, plotting the wrong values

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Im trying to plot a cdf in tikz, however it is plotting the wrong values and I have no idea why.

```
\documentclass{article

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={p(\k,\n) = 1-((\n!)/((\n^(\k))*((\n-\k)!)));}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, 
            xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$y$, 
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ymax=1.2, xmax=12.5,
            domain=0:12.5, samples at={0,...,12},
            no markers
                    ]
\addplot+ [ycomb, red, very thick] {p(x,2)}; % <----
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}}
```

Its the probability of a repeated result from k trials with n possible outcomes. When n=2, if k is 3 or greater the probability must clearly be 1, but tikz isnt plotting this.

[image: Latex plot]

This is what the function should look like with exactly the same equation in wolfram alpha:

[image: Correct plot]

Comment: The problem is that `pgfplots` struggles with calculating factorial from negative number. The somewhat meaningful value for `(-1)!` , `(-2)!`, ... is infinity, and WolframAlpha knows that, but `pgfplots` just sets these to 1.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about getting the correct plot in latex? Could I use a product sum to avoid using a factorial?

Comment: I would add an extra condition for `\n<\k` in `p(\k,\n)` and return 1 for this case.

Comment: Im very new to using latex, how would I add that condition into my code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` can compute `n!` only for nonnegative `n`, so one has to process the negative `n` case separately. In this simple case it's sufficient to multiply all the term with factorial by `(\n>=\k)`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={p(\k,\n) = 1-(\n>=\k)*((\n!)/((\n^(\k))*((\n-\k)!)));}
                    ]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle, 
            xlabel=$k$, ylabel=$y$, 
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ymax=1.2, xmax=12.5,
            domain=0:12.5, samples at={0,...,12}
                    ]
\addplot+ [ycomb, red, very thick] {p(x,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

gives the following (i've added some markers for clarity):

[image]